# ImportError when trying to import selectorlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pycharm, importerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/main.py", line 2, in <module>
import selectorlib
File "/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selectorlib/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from .selectorlib import Extractor  # noqa:F401
> >     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selectorlib/selectorlib.py", line 2, in <module>
import parsel
File "/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/parsel/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from parsel.selector import Selector, SelectorList  # NOQA
> >     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 21, in <module>
from lxml import etree, html
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister'
```

I reinstalled, upgraded and downloaded all the dependencies of lmxl and libxstl , but it's still not working.

My system is Macbook air m2

OS = MacOS Venture 13.0.1

I was trying to make a program to scrape web information by using the selectorlib module . In pycharm its showing the above error, in vscode it was showing that the module is not found .

Comment: Hi RaiyanKhan, I'm not sure how it work on MacOS but it looks like [lxml](https://lxml.de/) is not installed on your system. Have you tried installing it?

Comment: Yes i have installed lxml @EvensF

Comment: But is it installed in the virtual environment you have defined in /Users/raiyankhan/Desktop/Python projects/web-scraping/venv ?